# How can I Alias Data in a WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, alias, webgrid

I have an existing database that I can't change.  I have a column of type int that has various numbers that mean something.

This something would be a string.  For example, 1="dog", 2="cat", 3="bird".  There are a dozen or so integers to deal with.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with EF 4.1 and have a WebGrid binding to the Model.  Is there a way to alias the data for these integers listed in the WebGrid to display the string value that mean something to the user?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add an enum to your Model:

```
public enum foo
{
    dog = 1, cat, bird //etc
}
```

Hopefully, you are using ViewModels. If you are, add a property for the enum:

```
public foo thing {get;set;}
```

And set the value of `thing` based on the integer value you get from the database:

```
Model m = new Model{number = 3};
m.thing = (foo) m.number;
```

Or you could create a helper and use that within the format parameter to set a value based on the integer, or you could use JavaScript/jQuery to alter the values from ints to strings once they have been rendered to the browser.